# Chrome - "Open link in new tab" on right, "Reopen closed tab" in original position

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

When opening links in a new tab (by middle-clicking), I like the tab to appear at the far right, as it's usually for reading I'll get to later.

There are numerous extensions that will do this, but unfortunately all the ones I've found also affect the "Reopen closed tab" functionality, and cause reopened tabs to display on the far right as well.  I would like to have these reopened in the original position.

Are there any Chrome extensions that can open new links on the right, but maintain position for reopened tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried keyboard shortcuts. It works as expected in my system.

"Drag a link to a blank area on the tab strip" - This shortcut opens a link where ever you drag and drop it, and
Shift+Ctrl+T - Opens a "Reopen closed tab" at the original position

I use "Version 39.0.2171.71 m"

Comment: Ctrl+T opens a new empty tab, but what I'm after is for "Open Link in New Tab" (via the context menu or by middle clicking) to open links in tabs on the far right.  Thanks.

Comment: I found this shortcut in chrome support forum. "Drag a link to a blank area on the tab strip" to "Open link in new tab" at the right most tab or drag and drop the link where ever you want. Hope this helps. I have also, modified my above answer for others benefit.